# PDO: unbufferred queries error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I understand that this error is generated by a cursor being left open (not consuming all data). However, I thought I had suitably accounted for this by explicitly closing the cursor in my function. Nonetheless I am getting the error message

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while
>   other unbuffered queries are active.

Specifically this is being triggered when $setting ==0.
 What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php function selector($dbh, $selectString, &$callnumber, $setting)
                        {   
                            $callnumber++;
                            try{
                                $sth = $dbh->prepare($selectString);
                                $sth->execute();
                                if ($setting==0){
                                    $results     = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                                    $sth->closeCursor();
                                    return $results;
                                    }
                                else if ($setting==1){
                                    $moduleselect = array();
                                    while ($results = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                        $moduleselect[] = $results;
                                        $sth->closeCursor();
                                    }

                                    return $moduleselect;
                                }
                            }
                            catch (PDOException $e) {
                                echo($e->getMessage());
                                echo ("ref= ".$callnumber);
                                $dhh=null;
                                die();
                            }

                        }
?>
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. Do you get a different or better result if you also set `$sth = null;` after closing it?  And are you certain `$setting` is `0`? If its value is neither 0 nor 1, your logic will fall through to the end of the function, and since `execute()` was called that would definitely lead to the error you're experiencing -- you only fetch & close it if 0 or 1 was matched.